# Ignore Gemfile `source` if source not accessible

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

We have an internal gem server to store some organisation specific gems. We use it via a source option in `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://local-gems.example.com' do
  gem 'local-gem'
end
```

The internal gem server is only available on the internal network.

If I am off the network I can run `bundle` if:

1. I comment out the `source` declaration (and associated `end`)
2. The gems defined in the source group are already installed on the system.

That means that if I am working from home, I need to remember to comment out the `source` declaration, and then remember to uncomment it again before committing any change.

Is there a way to modify the `Gemfile` so that it will detect that the source is unavailable and ignore it? That is, can I configure `Gemfile` so I don't have to comment out those lines each time I work away from the local network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add arbitrary Ruby to your Gemfile, so you could do something like:

```
if (some check if hostname resolves)
  source 'https://local-gems.example.com' do
    gem 'local-gem'
  end
end
```

So for example, you can use `curl` like this:

```
local_source = if system('curl -s https://local-gems.example.com > /dev/null') != false
  # `curl` not available (`nil` returned) 
  #  or local gem server accessible (`true` returned) 
  #  try accessing:
  'https://local-gems.example.com'
else
  # Fall back on default behaviour
  'https://rubygems.org'
end

source local_source do
  gem 'local-gem'
end
```

Comment: You're right, using `system` is a better option. Thank you for that edit to my edit.

Comment: I've modified the answer so that it only falls back to the default behaviour if the system is sure that the local gem server is not available. If `curl` is not available, the system will try to connect to the local gem server. If it then isn't present, the error message will reflect that.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196549/hide-curl-output for purpose of `> /dev/null`